# struggling with NSDateFormatter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a strange issue between the simulator and a real run in an iPhone 6+ with NSDateFormatter in swift. I'm trying to convert a string in a specific format I get in JSON to NSDate with the following extension:

```
extension String {
var asStringDate: NSDate? {
    get {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let offsetTime = NSTimeInterval(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT) //support local timezone
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy H:mm"
        if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self) {
            let finalDate = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(offsetTime) //support local timezone
            //                if Constants.debug { println("\(self) -> \(finalDate)") }    //For debugging purposes
            return finalDate
        }
         println("Error while formating string:'\(self)' to date in String.asStringDate")     //For debugging purposes
        return nil
    }
}
```

for some reason, on the simulator runs OK but while running from the Xcode on my iPhone I get nil from

```
dateFormatter.dateFromString(self)
```

example of the string I get: "Fri, 19 Jun 2015 15:52"
any ideas why it fails in the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, the problem was in the line:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```

in which I set the currentLocale, in the moment I fixed to a specific locale instead of the default (in iPhone and mac apparently are not the same, so for each one there is a different value).
changing the line to:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

solved the problem, now the extension is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The different behaviors in parsing the date string to date object is caused by the different locale on your device and simulator. Depending on different locales, you need to change the date format accordingly.

If the date string you get is set by your backend server, you need to make sure it's set in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (for example 2015-08-02T21:50:49Z) so that it can be easily parsed and converted to date object in any locale.

Comment: hi, I don't have a way to change the format in the server where I'm getting the data from, and is clear that I have a problem with the locale, this is why I published the code, expecting maybe to get a suggestion about it or what I'm doing wrong, since I thought I was handling the locale in the code. thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: Well, in case you can't change server response format, you can also try to hard code the locale for the date formatter, for example: `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")`. This should work.

Comment: this is what I did if you see, I posted the answer yesterday before your message, thanks anyway